# All Solutions to $z^a= \bar{z}^b$

Tags: complex-numbers

All solutions to $z^a= \bar{z}^b$ where the integers a > b > 0.

I tried turning these into $e^{i\theta}$ and $e^{i\theta}$, then looked at how they could be interpreted through perhaps De Moivers, but still am not sure how to tackle.

I thought about just geometric reasoning, but that doesn't seem sufficient with the exponential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $a > b$ you must have $|z| = 1$ and $\bar z = 1/z$.  Thus you need to find all solutions to $z^{a+b} = 1$, where $a+b$ is a positive integer.

EDIT: there is also the trivial solution $z=0$.

Comment: Please explain why $|z|=1$?

Comment: $|z^a| = |z|^a$ and $|z| = |\bar z|$.

Comment: oh, yes. I got it.

Comment: Thanks very much. Could you elaborate any more on where to go from there to find all solutions? Wouldn't it just be 0,1? Was my notion of turning it into $e^{i\theta}$ completely unneeded?

Comment: $z^n = 1$ has exactly $n$ solutions on the unit circle if $n$ is a natural number. If you write $z^n = 1 = e^{2 \pi i k}$, $k \in \mathbb Z$,  you find $z = e^{2\pi i k/n}$, $k \in \mathbb Z$.  There are $n$ distinct such numbers.